pandas read_sql: Exclude null values from a select statement to a database call using pd.read_sql
I am running a panda read sql select statement and wish to exclude rows from my output where a certain field is NULL.
In standard SQL (Oracle, mySql, ms_sql) I would use where field_name is not null. I have attempted to use that code in my pd.read_sql but the result returns null values for the field I am trying to limit the output from, based on null values. My current workaround is to use length(field_name) > 0.
My example code is here:
import pandas as pd
import time

Result3 = pd.read_sql("Select gcdu_flatten.cbid_code, gcdu_flatten.incorporation_country, gcdu_flatten.gid_original, gcdu_flatten.local_cust_id, gcdu_flatten.saracen_id "
                      " FROM rm_views_uat_wave.gcdu_flatten "
                      " WHERE gcdu_flatten.etlmonth in ('2024-04-30') " 
                     #" and gcdu_flatten.saracen_id is not null "  ##This statement does NOT limit the data output to rows where the 'saracen_id is not null'
                      " and length(gcdu_flatten.saracen_id) > 0 " ##My current workaround to exclude null values for the field 'saracen_id'
                      , conn)

Any suggestions are most welcome. Thanks!

readsql returns a dataframe, or maybe you have a dataframe in the first place ? in both case just use dropna function on the dataframe (the subset parameter define the collumn you want to check for null values)
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Have you made sure sql query is working when executed directly on the server/ int eh database? Maybe the values arent Null

Thanks @titouanbou - Having tried using the dropna() function  i don't get the expected results, which does make me believe they are indeed not null values. I need to do some digging; alas i dont have direct server access to check the data value and type, but Ill reach out to those who do.

Thanks @BERA. Having tried using the dropna() function  i don't get the expected results, which does make me believe they are indeed not null values. I need to do some digging; alas i dont have direct server access to check the data value and type, but Ill reach out to those who do.
